# Finding number of active incidents in a week from the start and end date

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a data frame(df) which contains the arrival and closed date of incidents, of the format:

```
ID       ArrivalDate    ClosedDate       
        
1          2015-12-01     2015-12-08
2          2015-12-01     2015-12-18
3          2015-12-02     2015-12-11 
4          2015-12-02     2015-12-03 
.             .              .           
.             .              .           
300        2016-05-03      2016-05-13
```

I want to find out how many were active(which have arrived but not closed) per week, starting from 2015-12-01 to 2016-05-31. ie. The output should look something like this(this is not the right output values, just what it should look like).

Weeknumber    StartDate    EndDate       Active

```
1          2015-12-01   2015-12-08      4
2          2015-12-08   2015-12-15      15
3          2015-12-15   2015-12-22      20
.             .              .           .
.             .              .           .
26         2016-05-24  2016-05-31        3
```

I used the two for loops comparing each element in df with the start and end date of each week.
Also, I used a data frame(Week) which already has week number, start and end date for each week and number which is active(which is all zero in the beginning)

This is the code I used :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(Week)){
        if(df$ArrivalDate[i]>=Week$StartDate[j]&df$ArrivalDate[i]<Week$EndDate[j])                 
            Week$Active[j]<-Week$Active[j]+1
        
        if(df$ClosedDate[i]>=Week$EndDate[j]){
            k<-j+1    
                repeat{      
                Week$Active[k]<-Week$Active[k]+1
                if(df$ClosedDate[i]>=Week$EndDate[k])break
                k<-k+1
                }
        }     
        
        if(df$ClosedDate[i]<Week$EndDate[j])break            
    }
 }
```

I keep getting errors in if statements like "argument is of length zero" or "missing value where TRUE/FALSE are needed" which makes me believe NA values are getting created somehow. I don't know if its a mistake in my logic or some syntax problem I'm overlooking.

Comment: How do we come to know if the incidents are closed or not?

Comment: The data frame df has a column called ClosedDate. The incident becomes active on it's arrival (ArrivalDate) and becomes inactive on the ClosedDate

Comment: Can you explain it with the help of one example?

Comment: If I consider only the first four entries of df, I would get the number of active incidents in : first week(2015-12-01 to 2015-12-08) = 4, second week(2015-12-08 to 2015-12-15)=3, third week(2015-12-15 to 2015-12-22)=1. PS. when I say first week, it includes 2015-12-01, but not 2015-12-08. so, even though the ClosedDate for the first entry is 2015-12-08 it is still considered active for second week.